# Change an NSSet of NSNumber into an NSSet of int

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data, nsset

I'm using the data with core data and get an NSSet of NSNumber... my question is how can I do to change easily all the objects into int values? or can I directly get the int values from the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSSet` cannot store primitive values such as `int`, that's why `NSNumber` is used. Often you can just use `NSNumber` without doing any casting. If you do need the int value call `[mynumber intValue]`.

Comment: Thanks... I was hoping for a direct solution like perform selection!

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer your question, but it's related and it's insanely useful.

Let's say I have a collection (`NSArray`, `NSSet`, etc) of objects of a certain type, and these objects have a method/property called `displayValue` that somehow transforms the object into a more user-friendly format for displaying.  To transform my collection of objects into a collection of their displayValues, I only need to do:

```
NSArray * objects = ...;
NSArray * objectDisplayValues = [objects valueForKey:@"displayValue"];
```

The only caveat is that if `displayValue` returns a primitive (`int`, `float`, a struct, etc), it will be boxed into the appropriate `NSValue` container.

So theoretically you could do:

```
NSArray * numbers = ...;
NSArray * intValues = [numbers valueForKey:@"intValue"];
```

But since the `intValue` would be boxed into an `NSNumber`, you'd be right back where you started.

As I said, this isn't exactly an answer, but it's dead useful.

Comment: It's good to know that KVC works for method name as well as for property name

Answer (score 1):

Keep the NSSet as it is.

You can get the int values of an NSNumber easily.

```
int intValue = [myNSNumber intValue];
```